# What the mass matrix represents?

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations

I'm having a really hard time understanding the concept behind the mass matrix in the discretization of PDEs (I get the stiffness one, but not this one), also I know that is related to the identity (like the identity "moved").
Can someone make light on this doubts ? 
Thank you

EDIT: Since I have not put any background on it, generally speaking could someone explain the difference between mass matrix and stiffness matrix ?  Like, why in a lot of examples there is only the stiffness matrix and not the mass matrix ? When we need it ?

Comment: Please provide the definition of mass matrix you are working with. This would allow you to get a more suitable answer

Comment: Actually I don't have one, this is my problem. Somewhere I saw that is like the $L^2$ norm, but I don't know. Starting from having a PDE, and do all the process to get an algebraic equation in matrix-vector form, when here can be the mass matrix? In general, what is it ?

Comment: Please Google the definition, add it to your post, then highlight the parts you find difficult to understand. It will help you and whoever finds this question later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a base $\{b_j\}$ of some discrete subspace $V_h\subset V$ where $V$ is usually some Sobolev space on a domain $\Omega$, the mass matrix is the matrix $M=(m_{j,k})$ with
$$m_{j,k}=\int_\Omega b_j(x)b_k(x)\,dx.$$
It can be considered as the discrete version of the $L_2(\Omega)$ inner product on $V_h$.

*Edit:* Consider the simple problem: find $u\in V_h$ (with $V_h=\mathrm{span}\{b_j:j=1,\ldots,n\}$ as before) such that 
$$u_h=f$$
for some given function $f\in L_2(\Omega)$. Of course for $f\notin V_h$ we there is no solution in strong sense. But we can go over to the weak form. To this end we multiply with testfunctions $v_h$ and integrate to find the variational formulation
$$\int_\Omega u_h(x) v_h(x)\, dx=\int_\Omega f(x) v_h(x)\, dx,\quad\forall v_h\in V_h$$
Now plug in $u_h=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j b_j$ and all basis functions $b_j$ for $v_h$ and you end up with
$$M \alpha=F,$$
with $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)^T$,
$F=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)^T$ and
$$f_j=\int_\Omega b_j(x)f(x)\,dx.$$
Thus, the mass matrix appears naturally when you want to approximate a given function $f$ in a discrete space.

The stiffness matrix consists of entries 
$$s_{j,k}=\int_\Omega\nabla b_j(x)\cdot\nabla b_k(x)\,dx.$$
It is the discrete version of the $H^1(\Omega)$ semi-norm.

These matrices appear in finite element discretizations of PDEs. For example a discretization of Poisson's equation with homogenous Neumann boundary data and right hand side $f$ i.e.
\begin{align}
-\Delta u(x)&=f(x),&x&\in\Omega\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(x)&=0,&x&\in\partial\Omega\\
\end{align}
would be 
$$S\alpha=F$$
with $\alpha,F$ as before.

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting near to understand, thank you! Just this last thing. I can explain the stiffness matrix: Starting from the bilinear form definition (integral of the product between the gradients) inside the variational formulation, through Galerikin we have in the end the famous Ax=b, and so I can understan why the components of A are the bilinear forms. But I don't understand a "path" like that which bring us then the mass matrix.

Comment: I added an example where the mass matrix appears in a similar way

Comment: You can also consider PDEs which contain plain $u$, for example Helmholtz' equation, etc...

Comment: Ok now I can see the thought behind it, thank you a lot! Do you maybe know also the reason behind the term "mass" matrix ?